# Is the boundary of a 2-dimention-open-connect-bounded set a line?

Tags: general-topology, vector-analysis

Is the boundary of a 2-dimension open-connected bounded set a line?
By intuition, it seems right. But why?

Comment: Probably locally homeomorphic to a line I think, since it's (always?) going to be homeomorphic to a circle: think about an open disk centered at the origin.  Not sure of a quick and simple proof off the top of my head though.  Notice that you can get some other stuff, like a double line, if you remove the boundedness condition.

Comment: Nope, not locally homeomorphic to a line either. For example take the open disk centered at the origin and remove the positive $x$ axis. The boundary is homeomorphic to a circle with a line segment attached.

Comment: My question seems not to be so clear. I mean not distinguish "one line" and "more than one line". I mean to ask why it is (always?) line. No matter how many line attached.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip, would that not disconnect the set?

Comment: Ohhh, *positive* $x$-axis.  Very nice!!  Then it can't even be locally homeomorphic to a line because removing that $1$ point disconnects it into $3$ components.  I'm tempted to write this up as a response, but it's your idea, so I'd be happy to +1 you.  @TriệuĐỗ, think about Parsnip's counterexample.

Comment: @TriệuĐỗ: Are you asking whether the boundary is always connected?

Comment: @Parsnip: I'm afraid not, dear friend. Such a set as I mentioned, we naturally say that its boundary is a line, a curve or a union of these. But is it neccesary to be checked clearly? Let us take a homomorphism of your unit disk, which is no longer a disk. We can guess its boundary must be a simple close curve. But can we prove it must be a simple close curve?